# What are best practices for naming nodes, edges, and properties in IBM Graph?

Tags: graph-databases, tinkerpop, ibm-graph

I'm creating a schema for a graph in IBM Graph.  I've heard it's a best practice for the names of my nodes, edges, and properties to all be lower case.  What are other best practices?

For example, what are typical best practices regarding the following:

- spaces
- dashes
- underscores
- camel case

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this a best practice , but more of a way to avoid mis-typing names in your queries. It's better to use a consistent naming scheme for your names. For example , using lower case names for the first letter in your properties and vertex/node names. Use camel case for the rest. For example a vertex label could be "stackOverflowQuestion"